# Possible Duplicate returns 404

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, deleted-questions

The question https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/159369/67524 is marked as a duplicate, however the duplicate [link](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/159294/is-entity-framework-reliable-enough-to-use-in-a-corporate-project-should-i-use) returns 404.

What is the appropriate action going forward here?

- Should the question be closed?
- Should the question be removed in its entirety?

I feel like this creates a bad impression of members and visitors looking for this information.

I did see [Are you guys turning P.SE into a 404 black hole?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3969/67524) which seems to address a larger issue, but I would like to focus on this question in particular here.

Comment: related: [Don't let users vote to delete posts that are the target of dupes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239597/165773)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original question was written by the same guy.  Their first question got closed as "not constructive" (Too Broad, essentially), so he decided to re-ask it on Stack Overflow, where it promptly got migrated to Programmers and closed as a duplicate.

So not much to see here, really.

In the future, just flag for moderator attention with a custom reason, and explain the problem.  No need for a meta post on every one of these.  I've already flagged the question in question.